# remap tmux keys to navigate panes as in vim

Tags: tmux

I navigate panes in `vim` by hitting `Ctrl+w` release + `an arrow key (left|right|down|up)` .

I'd like to change my `tmux` config so the pane navigation is the same as in `vim` so I don't have to context switch.

Currently, I have the following config for navigating the panes in `tmux`:

```
bind-key j select-pane -D
bind-key k select-pane -U
bind-key h select-pane -L
bind-key l select-pane -R
```

My global prefix is set to `C-f` so I can navigate between panes by hitting `C-f + arrowkey`.

Is there a way how I can remap this to `C-w + arrowkey` like in `vim`?

I've tried something like this but that got me nowhere

```
bind -n C-w-j select-pane -D
bind -n C-w-k select-pane -U
bind -n C-w-h select-pane -L
bind -n C-w-l select-pane -R
```

I'm misunderstanding how the composition of the keys works in `tmux`, but the docs haven't helped much.

Comment: (1) In the code snippets you used `j`, `k`, `h`, `l`. Does your `arrowkey` mean one of these instead of actual arrow keys? (2) By `C-w + arrowkey` do you mean "`Ctrl+w`, release all, `arrowkey`"? or "`Ctrl+w`, release `w`, `Ctrl+arrowkey`"? or what? In [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1560646/432690) I have used a formatting that is pretty unambiguous in the subject of when to release what; it can be done. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: `arrowkey` means actual arrow key e.g. `up`, `down`, left` or `right`. By `Ctrl+w + arrowkey` I mean `Ctrl+w` release `arrowkey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man 1 tmux`, where it describes `bind-key`, states:

> Keys may also be bound in custom key tables and the `switch-client -T` command used to switch to them from a key binding.

The relevant part about `switch-client` [emphasis mine]:

> `-T` sets the client's key table; the next key from the client will be interpreted from `key-table`. **This may be used to configure multiple prefix keys**, or to bind commands to sequences of keys.

Let's name our new custom key table `Cw`. We want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to select it, then we want arrow keys it this table to select panes accordingly. This:

```
bind-key    -T root C-w   switch-client -T Cw
bind-key -r -T Cw   Right select-pane   -R
bind-key -r -T Cw   Left  select-pane   -L
bind-key -r -T Cw   Up    select-pane   -U
bind-key -r -T Cw   Down  select-pane   -D
```

You may or may not prefer these bindings without `-r`.

Comment: This actually doesn't seem to have done the trick. I think there might be something else at play. But I learnt from your answer that I can create a new key table which is something I didn't know. I noticed I have this key binding somehow `bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-w                  send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel` but I can't see it in my config file so that's...strange

Comment: @milosgajdos Did you restart the tmux server after altering `.tmux.conf`? Or did you reload the file?

Comment: I started a new session by `tmux -f test-tmux.conf` to test it out.

Comment: See the beginning of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757783/108618). Restart the tmux server or [reload the config](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373409/108618) or run the commands manually (in a shell inside tmux: `tmux bind-key …` and so on).

Comment: oh, wow, that did the trick indeed. Thanks, accepting your answer :-)

Comment: But I have also now realized that it broke pane cycling in my `vim` when I open it inside a `tmux` session  so it seems one doesn't seem to be able to get both. Either `tmux` wins or `vim` does  But your answer does do the job in the `tmux`

Comment: @milosgajdos I think it's possible to program tmux to check if the foreground application is vim and if so, pass the keystroke to it; otherwise use the keystroke to select another tmux pane. But once in vim, there will be no easy way to jump "out". I mean I think there is no easy way for tmux to know if a pane in vim is e.g. the rightmost vim pane and thus the keystroke to go right should select another tmux pane instead of being passed to vim. You would need to program vim to cooperate: if it cannot change the pane it should check if it's in tmux and run `tmux select-pane …` accordingly.